# Animated relayout of web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have an html `table` where cells contain `span`s. Some action causes the divs `span`s to change their position, for instance, I reconstruct the table transposed.

Consider

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id='cell1'>1</td>
    <td id='cell2'>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id='cell3'>3
        <div id='el'>foo</div>
    </td>
    <td id='cell4'>4</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
  setTimeout(function () {
       document.getElementById('cell2').appendChild(document.getElementById('el'))
  }, 2000);
```

How can I animate the `span`s' positional change?

My first take on the problem is to create the new table hidden, on top the old one, save the absolute postions of each `span`, old and new, place absolutely position copies of the `span`s on top of the old ones, animate them to their new positions, delete the old table, reveal the new table and finally delete the absolutely position `span` copies.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This question is eating away at my rep. I would not have guessed it. Does anybody know why?

Comment: If I would have to guess I would say paste the code from fiddle and create a scripted sample here too. Good luck.

Comment: Is this question "too broad", i.e. according to definition a) too many possible answers or b) answers would be very long. 

As for b, strictly this is a yes or no answer, but of course I'm expecting a longer answer. But I've given one answer and it's not very long. But perhaps all the rest are very much longer and if so, I'd very much like to know. Since I have one solution, in that case I would go with it.

As for a, entirely possible. I'd be very happy to get just a few or just one of those numerous possible answers.

Comment: I don't question why too broad questions are not appropriate, but it would be strange, when I've always turned to SO for answers to my problems that all of a sudden I should be turned away without so much as an indication to where I might look for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, how about using the [CSS transition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) property?

I dont think you need to create a copy of the entire table and do any calculations.

For an example, lets assume you want to move the updated span upwards. You can define a CSS class that contains the necessary padding like in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/63uamuup/) and simply add that CSS class to the span you are updating.

A single line of CSS like this, lets you animate the spans movement:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

**EDIT**

I was able to animate your fiddle with the help of [this article by Tim Taubert](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/)

[You can find the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/710ao3k5/1/)

Comment: Yes, I was planning on using the transition property although I don't think it will work on its own, unless I've misunderstood. I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpx8abdh/

Comment: oh cool the example helps! let me see if I can figure something out

Comment: @Martin does this help?

Comment: Umm, it certainly moves an element between cells and without a doubt there is animation. It's a step.